# video presentation application for linux

Tags: linux, video, presentations

I am looking for an application to create video presentations in linux.
I have made one with the online service animoto.com that i really like, but i am looking to make one with a little more control over it. For example i would like to control how the pictures are shown ( the duration ).

Is there any good app on linux for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.  Here are a few suggestions for editing video on Linux (please look for them on Google, I'm not allowed to post more than one link):

- GIMP Animation Package
- Cinelerra
- Kino
- Jahshaka
- LiVES

For a longer list, see [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Videobearbeitung) - the website's in German, but full of links ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [OOImpress](http://www.openoffice.org/product/impress.html)

> IMPRESS is a truly outstanding tool for creating effective multimedia presentations. Your presentations will stand out with 2D and 3D clip art, special effects, animation, and high-impact drawing tools.

Comment: that is more for slideshow presentation, i want it for turning pictures into a video presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try Vidlang

> Video Language (or VidLang, sometimes referred to as just Video) is a DSL for editing...videos. It aims to merge the capabilities of a traditional graphical non-linear video editor (NLVE), with the power of a programming language.

https://github.com/videolang/video